# What's the difference between "weit" and "fern"?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, difference, german-to-english

Both of them translate as "far", but what are the differences in meaning and usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fern**:

"Fern" (nearly synonymous with "entfernt") is used to describe something taking place far away (in time, in space or figuratively), cf. to English: "distant", "far away" or something like that.

> "Dich zu beleidigen, liegt mir fern!"
>
> "Vielleicht sehen wir uns eines nicht allzu fernen Tages wieder."
>
> "Eines Tages will ich in ein fernes Land ziehen."
>
> "Dieser Vorschlag ist realitätsfern!"

**"Weit"**

"Weit" can be used much more often, with more different meanings.
[Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=weit) also suggests "broad", "large", "wide", "vast" and "ample" as different translations for "weit", it also lists different examples.
More examples can be found [here](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/weit).

> "Die Hose ist mir zu weit" (-> "wide")
>
> "Dieses Forschungsthema ist ein weites Feld" (-> "broad")
>
> "Der Kapitän ließ seinen Blick über das weite Meer schweifen" (-> "vast")

However, it can also have a very similar meaning to "fern".

> "Diese Entscheidung liegt noch weit in der Zukunft."

Here, you might as well write:

> "Diese Entscheidung liegt noch fern in der Zukunft."

To me, the tiny difference would be that "weit" generally rather refers to the quality of the *distance or extension* between the speaker and something far away, whereas "fern" only states that a thing *is* far away, as in:

> "Der Weg ist noch weit."

vs.

> "Das Ziel liegt fern."

Comment: "Fern" can often be translated as "remote", as in "Fernbedienung" = "Remote control".

Comment: "Weit" kann auch komplett ohne räumliche Komponente verwendet werden. "Zu weit gehen". "Man ist weit gekommen". Hierfür scheidet "fern" als Ersatz aus.